# How to limit number of lines in RichEdit

Tags: android

I'm a beginner in android . But after a lot of try and reference I've designed a text editor using this library [RichEditor](https://github.com/wasabeef/richeditor-android)

It seems to be a webview.Everything is working fine but I wonder how can I limit the lines of text that can be entered. I've searched a lot in SO questions but nothing could help me

My Code:

```
RichEditor rE=findViewById(R.id.editor);
rE.setEditorFontSize(22);
//We can change the background and text color of text but how to limit 
lines of text?
```

Comment: @AkashPal I've added some code but I think it would be better if you could check that library for a while

Comment: I've already tried that but it's not limiting text